# GIT updates working tree with receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead even for rejected pushes (receive.denyNonFastForwards=true)

Tags: git

I posted this question/bug to the GIT official channel but got no response. Hoping someone here can help me.

The below behavior seems incorrect to me when **receive.denyCurrentBranch** is set to **updateInstead** and
**receive.denyNonFastForwards** is set to **true**. Below are the steps to
reproduce the scenario.

**Step 1 - Setup remote repository (remote host):**

```
git config --global receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
git config --global receive.denyNonFastForwards true
mkdir /tmp/hello
cd /tmp/hello
git init
echo hello > hello.txt
git add . && git commit -m "hello.txt"
```

**Step 2 - Create 2 Clones (local host):**

```
git clone ssh://REMOTEIP/tmp/hello /tmp/hello1
git clone ssh://REMOTEIP/tmp/hello /tmp/hello2
```

**Step 3 - Push a commit from Clone 1**

```
cd /tmp/hello1
echo hello1 > hello1.txt
git add . && git commit -m "hello1.txt"
git push
```

At this point server working tree contains hello1.txt which is expected

**Step 4: Try to force push a commit from Clone 2**

```
cd /tmp/hello2
echo hello2 > hello2.txt
git add . && git commit -m "hello2.txt"
git push
```

Remote rejects with message that remote contains work i do not have locally which is valid. Now I force the push.

```
git push --force
```

Remote rejects again with error: **denying non-fast-forward
refs/heads/master (you should pull first)**

At this point, since the push is rejected, I expect the servers
working tree to not contain any rejected changes. BUT the servers
working tree got updated to delete hello1.txt and create hello2.txt.
Push rejected but not really.

I also noticed the same behavior (incorrect) when the update hook
rejects changes on the server (but not the pre-receive hook).

Comment: This is fixed with Git 2.20 (Q4 2018): see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53137331/6309)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that these two configurations are in conflict (though I agree that in principle they *shouldn't* be):

> `receive.denyCurrentBranch` is set to `updateInstead`

In this case, during the receive, Git notices that the target is the current branch, so Git checks out the commit.

> and `receive.denyNonFastForwards` is set to `true`.

This happens separately: the change to the *name* is rejected.  The commit was already taken, and the repository checkout happened, and *now* the change to the *name* is rejected.

> I also noticed the same behavior (incorrect) when the update hook rejects changes on the server (but not the pre-receive hook).

This is the same issue: the pre-receive hook runs once, before any individual reference updates, and can reject the entire push.  Then, if the pre-receive hook has cleared things to proceed, the update hooks can reject any individual ref-name update.  However, `updateInstead` happens separately from the branch name update being accepted or rejected.

It would probably be better for Git to internally avoid the working-tree change until *after* vetting the reference update.  This would require some rework in Git's internals.  If this isn't considered an outright bug in Git, it's at least quite surprising.  In fact, all of this code needs some work anyway because if you use `git worktree add`, Git fails to consider the added worktrees' HEADs as current branches.  Given all of these caveats, I'd recommend using only bare repositories as push targets, with post-receive hooks to direct updates in other repositories or work-trees.

---

Aside (this was a comment, but that was too short to express it very well):

> ```
> git config --global receive.denyCurrentBranch updateInstead
> git config --global receive.denyNonFastForwards true
> ```

Although this is not tied to the specific behavior you've observed, this is definitely the wrong thing to do.  Running `git config --global` sets configuration items for you, personally.  That is, these go into `/home/rajesh` (or wherever your home directory configuration resides).  But `receive.*` settings should be *per-repository*.

Since you are using `ssh` as yourself to do the push, these configuration parameters did take effect—but if you were ever to push via some other method, they might not.  Any per-repository settings, made with `git config` without `--global`, would still take effect.

Comment: definitely understand the concern with --global but thanks for the answer and pointing out the global config concern. Based on your explanation and to get the behavior I want, (using one or more of the built in receive.deny* options along with updating remote work tree), do you think that reimplementing the updateInstead functionality as a post-receive hook is a better approach? Basically doing a checkout in post-receive.

Comment: Yes, the post-receive method will work better. (In fact the `updateInstead` behavior and all related behaviors with `git worktree add` are bad, so servers should have bare repositories in the first place, and do any deployment tricks elsewhere, including post-receive hooks.)

Comment: Upvoted of course, but "It would probably be better for Git to internally avoid the working-tree change until after vetting the reference update." might be a little mild, if this isn't a [POLA](https://www.google.com/search?q=principle+of+least+astonishment) violation I don't know what would be.

Comment: @jthill: agreed. I think I'll emphasize that a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

> I expect the servers working tree to not contain any rejected changes. BUT the servers working tree got updated to delete hello1.txt and create hello2.txt.
>   Push rejected but not really.

From Git 2.20 onwards (Q4 2018), the push will *really* be rejected.

Before, the `receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead` codepath kicked in even when the push should have been rejected due to other reasons, such as it does not fast-forward or the update-hook rejects it, which has been corrected.

See [commit b072a25](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b072a25fad21b8aecfa29f6ffb813a0a6194a764) (19 Oct 2018) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4c7f544](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c7f5440225aba8f0c7253575e5ffa933a267de7), 30 Oct 2018)</sup>

> ### `receive`: `denyCurrentBranch=updateinstead` should not blindly update
>
> The handling of `receive.denyCurrentBranch=updateInstead` was added to
>   a switch statement that handles other values of the variable, but
>   all the other case arms only checked a condition to reject the
>   attempted push, or let later logic in the same function to still
>   intervene, so that a push that does not fast-forward (which is
>   checked after the switch statement in question) is still rejected.
>
> But the handling of `updateInstead` incorrectly took immediate effect,
>   without giving other checks a chance to intervene.
>
> Instead of calling `update_worktree()` that causes the side effect
>   immediately, just note the fact that we will need to call the
>   function later, and first give other checks a chance to reject the
>   request.
>   After the `update-hook` gets a chance to reject the push (which happens as the last step in a series of checks), call `update_worktree()` when we earlier detected the need to.

In your case, your working tree will *not* contain any rejected change, as expected, considering your push was rejected.

---

Torek added:

> In fact, all of this code needs some work anyway because if you use `git worktree add`, Git fails to consider the added worktrees' HEADs as current branches

Well no more.

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), "`git push`" should stop from updating a branch that is checked out when `receive.denyCurrentBranch` configuration is set, but it failed to pay attention to checkouts in secondary worktrees.

> This has been corrected.

See [commit 4d86489](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d864895a23bbbb5403d9aa8a65d0576d2029597) (04 Mar 2020), and [commit 4ef3464](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ef346482d6d5748861c1aa9d56712e847369b40), [commit f869211](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f8692114dbb1b3ffe0b71871a015c632c195b784), [commit 45f274f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45f274fbb118cc4cb00640c30b4e3069d96755a0) (23 Feb 2020) by [Hariom Verma (`harry-hov`)](https://github.com/harry-hov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4a2e91d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a2e91db652e197803c6f29e2c2f1c9dfbc16506), 05 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`receive.denyCurrentBranch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4ef346482d6d5748861c1aa9d56712e847369b40): respect all worktrees
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>
>   <sup>Signed-off-by: Hariom Verma</sup>
>
> The `receive.denyCurrentBranch` config option controls what happens if you push to a branch that is checked out into a non-bare repository.
>   By default, it rejects it.
>   It can be disabled via `ignore` or `warn`. Another yet trickier option is `updateInstead`.
>
> However, this setting was forgotten when the [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) command was introduced: only the main worktree's current branch is respected.
>
> **With this change, all worktrees are respected**.
>
> That change also leads to revealing another bug, i.e. `receive.denyCurrentBranch = true` was ignored when pushing into a non-bare repository's unborn current branch using ref namespaces.
>   As `is_ref_checked_out()` returns 0 which means `receive-pack` does not get into conditional statement to switch `deny_current_branch` accordingly (ignore, warn, refuse, unconfigured, updateInstead).
>
> `receive.denyCurrentBranch` uses the function `refs_resolve_ref_unsafe()` (called via `resolve_refdup()`) to resolve the symbolic ref HEAD, but that function fails when HEAD does not point at a valid commit.
>
> As we replace the call to `refs_resolve_ref_unsafe()` with `find_shared_symref()`, which has no problem finding the worktree for a given branch even if it is unborn yet, this bug is fixed at the same time: **`receive.denyCurrentBranch` now also handles worktrees with unborn branches as intended even while using ref namespaces**.